# MVC 4.0 Events in global.asax won't fire

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I'm using MVC 4.0.
The Events in global.asax fire when I browse the site by first going to the home page. The problem is when I surf to a direct page in the website with some url parameters, the Session_Start event won't fire.
Why?
Can I fire it manually?

Comment: Session_Start only triggers on your first visit and when the user session expires. If you are using session cookies did you delete it before visiting your site with url parameters?

Answer (score 2):

The session_start doesn't fire unless you are actually reading or writing to the session object.

If you want to utilize the session_start event but don't need to use the session store at all, you can add the following to the Controller

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class MyController : Controller
{
```

This will cause the session_start event to fire without you having to store anything in the session object.

Comment: Will it block me from writing to the session?

Comment: If Read-only session state is enabled for the request. This means that session state cannot be updated. This setting overrides whatever session state behavior would have been determined by inspecting the handler for the request.

Comment: Then I think it's best for me to just write some value to the session, so it will trigger the Session_Start event.

Comment: yes or you can simply read a previously stored value from the session object.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112363/discussion-between-psylogic-and-itay-b).